# How can I disable rotation overall

Tags: release-loki

Rotation is up side down and keeps being missed up with the slightest of movements, using Asus, once the installing is done the whole display is up side down and stay flipped however I turn the machine, also it is really sensitive, keeps rotating even if I simply move the laptop sideways. How can I disable rotation overall. "None in display settings does not work"